# Lattice to continuum transformation in one dimension (arbitrary range interaction)

Tags: field-theory, continuum-mechanics, lattice-model, phonons, displacement

Please help me convert the ionic displacement $u_l$ of the $l^{th}$ ion to a continuous field $u'(y)$ in the following problem. I am trying to derive the Hamiltonian of a 1-D lattice (spacing $=n_0^{-1}$)and want the final continuum harmonic Hamiltonian: $$H=\int dy \frac{p(y)^2}{2m n_0} + \frac{mn_0v^2}{2}(\partial_yu(y))^2.$$
So, I start with the lattice Hamiltonian:$$H_{lattice}=\sum_{l\neq l'}\frac{p_l^2}{2m}+V(x_l-x_l'),$$ where $p_l,x_l$ are momentum and position of $l^{th}$ ion. For small displacements $u_l$ from lattice point at location $l/n_0$ we can express $x_l$ as:$$x_l=l/n_0+u_l$$ The potential energy can now be expressed as:
$$V[x_l-x_l']\approx V[(l-l')/n_0 + (u_l-u_l')].$$
The gradient expansion (taylor series) gives an expansion about the mean ionic positions: $$V[x_l-x_l']\approx \sum_{l\neq l'}V\Big[\frac{l-l'}{n_0}\Big] + V'\Big[\frac{l-l'}{n_0}\Big](u_l-u_l')+\frac{1}{2!}V''\Big[\frac{l-l'}{n_0}\Big](u_l-u_l')^2+\ldots$$
We can expand $$(u_l-u_l')\approx u'(l') (l-l') + \frac{1}{2!}u''(l') (l-l')^2+\ldots,$$
Here is where I am stuck, I can't seem to figure out how to go from displacements of ions $u_l,$ to a continuous field $u(y)$. I know I can substitute $\frac{l-l'}{n_0}$ by a continuous variable $y$ but don't know how to handle $l$ and $l'$ separately. If you can point me to a source with a worked out example or explain it to me I will really appreciate it.
Thanks.